# Attempt to deploy laravel 5.5 with Vue app on shared hosting -component does not update

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vuejs2, shared-hosting

I' m trying to deploy my Laravel App on shared hosting. I'm also using Vuejs. Almost everything works fine. Only problem is component which is not updating after change. I'm doing following steps:

1. Copy Laravel project (files) from localhost to shared hosting. Project is working (except vue)
2. Installation of nodejs in root directory (not in laravel folder). I use following commands:

   2.1 wget -qO- https://cdn.rawgit.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash

   2.2 export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"

   2.3 [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"

   2.4 [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"

   2.5 nvm install node

   2.6 nvm use node
3. Next I'm going to laravel folder and input npm run watch but I get an error. Below is the content of log of npm

   ```
   0 info it worked if it ends with ok
   1 verbose cli [ '/home/mojstrona/.nvm/versions/node/v10.10.0/bin/node',
   1 verbose cli   '/home/mojstrona/.nvm/versions/node/v10.10.0/bin/npm',
   1 verbose cli   'run',
   1 verbose cli   'watch' ]
   2 info using npm@6.4.1
   3 info using node@v10.10.0
   4 verbose run-script [ 'prewatch', 'watch', 'postwatch' ]
   5 info lifecycle @~prewatch: @
   6 info lifecycle @~watch: @
   7 verbose lifecycle @~watch: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
   8 verbose lifecycle @~watch: PATH: /home/mojstrona/.nvm/versions/node/v10.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/mojstrona/domains/moj.stronazen.pl/l55/node_modules/.bin:/home/mojstrona/.nvm/versions/node/v10.10.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/home/mojstrona/.local/bin:/home/mojstrona/bin
   9 verbose lifecycle @~watch: CWD: /home/mojstrona/domains/moj.stronazen.pl/l55
   10 silly lifecycle @~watch: Args: [ '-c',
   10 silly lifecycle   'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js' ]
   11 silly lifecycle @~watch: Returned: code: 126  signal: null
   12 info lifecycle @~watch: Failed to exec watch script
   13 verbose stack Error: @ watch: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
   13 verbose stack Exit status 126
   13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/mojstrona/.nvm/versions/node/v10.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
   13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
   13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/mojstrona/.nvm/versions/node/v10.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
   13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
   13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
   13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
   14 verbose pkgid @
   15 verbose cwd /home/mojstrona/domains/moj.stronazen.pl/l55
   16 verbose Linux 3.10.0-714.10.2.lve1.5.17.el7.x86_64
   17 verbose argv "/home/mojstrona/.nvm/versions/node/v10.10.0/bin/node" "/home/mojstrona/.nvm/versions/node/v10.10.0/bin/npm" "run" "watch"
   18 verbose node v10.10.0
   19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
   20 error code ELIFECYCLE
   21 error errno 126
   22 error @ watch: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
   22 error Exit status 126
   23 error Failed at the @ watch script.
   23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
   24 verbose exit [ 126, true ]
   ```

I can solve this error using chmod -R a+x node_modules, bute I get next  error

```
error  in ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
Module build failed: Error: Missing binding /home/mojstrona/domains/moj.stronazen.pl/l55/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 10.x** Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to download the binding for your current environment.
```

So I'm restarting SSH and running npm rebuild node-sass without errors. Then I'm running npm run watch with any errors too, but the problem still exists. Components are not updated after changes even if I change component name. for example:

**Before change in app.js**

```
Vue.component('ex', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));
```

**Before change in components folder**

ExampleComponent.vue

**Displayed**

ExampleComponent.vue

**After change in app.js**

```
Vue.component('ex', require('./components/ExampleComponent2.vue'));
```

**After change in components folder**

ExampleComponent2.vue

**Displayed after change**

ExampleComponent.vue

**After change2 in app.js**

```
Vue.component('ex', require('./components/ExampleComponent2.vue'));
```

**After change2 in components folder**

ExampleComponent3.vue

**Displayed after change2**

ExampleComponent.vue

Below is the screenshot of result of npm run commands.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a shared hosting with SSH access so? So when you push code update and start a build, built files never change? Please check using FTP/SFTP/SSH: 1. Does the source file for build contain your updates? 2. Does the built file contain your changes? 3. If 2 is yes, it may be your browser caching files if you don't user versioned filenames.

Comment: Yes, updated content exist on server. I changed filename of updated component too. The problem still exists.

Comment: Did you check source files (in /resources) and built files (in /public)?

Comment: Please tell me exactly what should I check. Structure of public folder is typical. I have css,js,fonts folders,htacces etc..

Comment: When you deploy new code, I want you to check : 1. File is updated in your /resources folder. 2. Run npm build. 3. Check that built asset in /public contains updated code

Comment: 1, File is updated. 2, I ran npm build 3, In /public nothing changed. Structure of the folder is typical.

Comment: So, it's your npm build that is failing. As it should update /public files; What npm build outputs ?

Comment: npm build gives empty output (nothing)

Comment: No log file you can check? It could be a permission issue so npm fail to replace old build with new ones in your /public/ folder

Comment: Please look at my post. I described my action step by step.

Comment: Please run `npm rebuild node-sass` and `npm run` again. So issue is clearly from the npm build part. EDIT: ok your already done that. What's in the log after you fixed the permission issue, sass rebuild, and npm run again? Does it work locally?

Comment: I ran npm rebuild node-sass. Result - 'Binary is fine'. Next I ran npm run. As result I get prompt to choose npm run development, npm run watch, npm run production. Result of all three commands is "DONE Compiled successfuly in xxxx ms", but component is not updated even if I change filename.

Comment: So not any of the npm command output something? There is no détail output? Usually it output the source file and destination file with path... Does it works locally?

Comment: Yes, it works locally. Please look at my edited post with screenshoot.